# Mod rewrite only working on some computers

Tags: .htaccess

I've got a website where on the majority of computers it works absolutely fine, redirecting users to the correct pages using the .htaccess file.

However, some computers seem to be ignoring the rules in the .htaccess file (maybe even the .htaccess file completely).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^procyon$ /procyon.php [L]
```

When a user visits http://www.blackroc-technology.com/procyon it redirects them to a product page. However, for some users they get a 404 error.

Someone in the same building as me (same internet connection) is suffering from this problem - I've tried both IE and Chrome and neither work so it doesn't appear to be a browser issue.

There's also a handful of customers on other internet connections to ours which have reported the problem.

Any thoughts on this? It's seems very odd to me and hard to debug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can reproduce both cases, working and not working, then do an client side HTTP capture, e.g. using Fiddler.

You can then diff the successful/unsuccessful request to try to narrow down the issue e.g. if bad requests always fail and good requests always succeed, when re-requested from Fiddler, regardless of which network, computer they are issued, then it is likely a server side issue (.htaccess or httpd.conf setting sensitive to one of the request attributes).

At the very least you will have a better idea of exactly what is transpiring vs just the end result of a 404.

You can also similarly enable logging on the server side (ideally in a staging enviroment, not production) e.g

> RewriteLogLevel 9

to get more details on why bad requests result in a 404